# session expiry duration for "remember me" login users

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth

I am using oauth authentication and setting expiry for the login tokens. I have "Remember Me" checkbox at the login. My question is, should the users be logged in forever upon clicking "remember me" or is there any standard or recommended expiry duration that I need to configure?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no specific standard for setting up a duration of expiry. It all depends on how you (or the business) decide the website to be managed. One website might have a duration of 30 days for remember me whereas other websites might allow 365 days. Besides if you are using OAuth you can make the duration perpetual (never ending) by refreshing the expired token using a refresh token. Websites dealing with high value information (banking, financial, healthcare) generally do not have a remember me option because of security risk.